# Using FileField in a FormWizard (Django 1.3)

Tags: django, file-upload, formwizard, django-formwizard

I am trying to use a Django 1.3 FormWizard to upload a file with 2 steps:
1. Only the FileField
2. If the file was correctly uploaded and valid (after custom validation), offer to give it a name and description.

Following the documentation, I wrote:

```
class CreateCheckWizard(FormWizard):
    def done(self, request, form_list):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/my_checks/')
    def get_template(self, step):
        return ['create_check_%s.html' % step, 'create_check_1.html']

class CreateCheckForm1(forms.Form):
    my_file = forms.FileField()

class CreateCheckForm2(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I added the multipart/form-data to the FORM tag in the template:
`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="." method="post">`

However, even if I upload a file, I get the error "This field is required."

I guess the form is created omitting the request.FILES field.
How can we change that behaviour to successfully upload files in the FormWizard?

Edit: Looking at Django source code, it indeed create the forms using `form(request.POST)` instead of `form(request.POST, request.FILES)` like it should be to handle files.
Any way to upload files without changing the source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible in the Django 1.3 form wizard. From the [Django form wizard docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#defining-form-classes):

> **Important limitation:** Because the wizard uses HTML hidden fields to store data between pages, you may not include a FileField in any form except the last one

It is possible with the Django 1.4 form wizard (see [handling files docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#handling-files)). If you're using Django 1.3, you can install the new form wizard as a [separate app](https://github.com/stephrdev/django-formwizard#readme).

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. I saw it was available on 1,4 but as I am using 1.3, the external plugin you gave the link is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!